# SupportMapFragment with a custom layout, possible?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to have SupportMapFragment with a custom layout, right now the following code works :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        // initMap();
        return view;
    }
```

But I want to change the `onCreateView()` method to inflate a different layout, instead of calling the `super.onCreateView()` method.
To look like something like this:

```
View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container,false);
mMap = (GoogleMap)view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

But GoogleMap is not a `view` so I **cannot** add it to the xml, like the following way:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to create a SupportMapFragment with a custom layout, I prefer to extend the `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` from the Support Library and inflate your custom XML with the `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` and other views there.

But be careful to forward the livecycle methods to this `MapView` as quoted [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView).

Comment: I am getting a blank screen when trying to add the fragment to the screen.

Comment: Have you forwarded all the livecycle methods to the new `MapView`?  
  
        `((MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView)).onCreate(savedInstanceState);`  
  
in your fragment's `onCreate()` ?

Comment: Oh I need to call the method explicitly, I will try that. So I will need to override all the life cycle methods ?

Comment: As quoted from the API Reference:  
_Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods to the corresponding ones in this class, such as onCreate, onDestroy, onResume, onPause._

Comment: And how do you call mapview.onCreate(bundle); before onCreateView()?

Comment: `@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try {
MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return view;
}`

Answer (score 5):

I added a LinearLayout above the map.
I used this layout for the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/llPlaces"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/ACGris">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON1"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON2"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BUTTON3"/>
```

And then I created a class which extends SupportMapFragment

```
public class FrgMapas extends SupportMapFragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View viewMain = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View viewButtons = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_buttons, null);

    FrameLayout mainChild = (FrameLayout) ((ViewGroup)viewMain).getChildAt(0);
    mainChild.addView(viewButtons);

    Button btn1 = (Button) viewMain.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "TuTa :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return viewMain;
}
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: This fails on Android 2.3, since onCreateView() will return a framelayout with 12 null childs. In Android 4.1.2 I get another null pointer exception in later stages.

Answer (score 4):

`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` is a `View` that you can embed in your layouts.

Comment: @themilkman: `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` is from the v2 API. http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview

Comment: I am getting a blank screen after i'm adding the fragment to the screen, i have overriden the getmap so it will return the `getMap()` from the mapview.

Answer (score 1):

You can override onCreateView in the class you derive from SupportMapFragment. You can call super.onCreateView and then insert the result into a custom ViewGroup you inflater or instantiate.  Here's some sample code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout,
            container, false);

    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    layout.addView(v, 0);
    return layout;
}
```