# Android Google Maps v2: on click listener not responding

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to put a marker when the user clicks on map. I'm using a `SupportMapFragment` inside an `ActionBarActivity`. But the map doesn't respond, furthermore, a `map.setMapType()` operation isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
private GoogleMap map;
private Marker marker;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.select_location);
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Map","On view created");
    map = getMap();
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            Log.d("Map","Map clicked");
            marker.remove();
            drawMarker(point);
        }
    });

         ...
         Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
           //PLACE THE INITIAL MARKER              
           drawMarker(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
        }
}
```

Logcat is showing the "on view created" message and the map shows the current location with a marker, so the last part of the code is being executed. But the `onMapClickListener` is overrided or something because it doesn't work, and the map isn't a satellite.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have extended SupportMapFragment you can simply do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.select_location);  
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  map = getMap();
  map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
  map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        Log.d("Map","Map clicked");
        marker.remove();
        drawMarker(point);
    }
});
```

Note that getMap() is called in `onActivityCreated` and `inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false)` is not necessary if you don´t use a custom layout.

You don´t even need a map.xml layout!

You are extending `SupportMapFragment` but you are inflating another `MapView` (not the one tied to `SupportMapFragment` by default), that´s why you are not viewing the changes in your map. Because you were acting on the default `View` got from `getMap()` but you are viewing another. See the [docs about getMap()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment#getMap%28%29):

> ```
> public final GoogleMap getMap ()
> ```
>
> Gets the underlying GoogleMap that is tied to the view wrapped by this
>   fragment.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks josuadas! The point is that I need to inflate a XML because it's not a view with just a map. I think that it's still neccesary to extend SupportMapFragment, isn't it?

Comment: Ez horregatik! In my opinion you shouldn´t extend SupportMapFragment in that case but just Fragment (from support library). See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804511/supportmapfragment-with-a-custom-layout-possible

Comment: Another possibility is to add the SupportMapFragment to a FragmentActivity just taking up the space for the map. F.i. using a FrameLayout as container in your FragmentActivity layout: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime

Answer (score 2):

Well you are placing a listener for your map, but you need to make a listener for your markers.

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

...

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {     
    Log.i(TAG,"marker arg0 = "+arg0);               
    return false;
}
```

or for the InfoWindows on top of the markers:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
```

---

Also, your initialitizing of map making it show satelite is almost correct:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

change it to:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing map = getMap(), a few lines later I had this code:

```
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = fm.getMap();
```

So I've just put the code above that line and it's done.

Comment: Hi Jon! I think you can do in an easier way, because you are already in the SupportMapFragment, it´s not necessary to get the Fragment (it´s useful when you call from the FragmentActivity). I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing map = getMap() you can try this.

```
if (map == null) {
    // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    this.map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView))
        .getMap();
    setUpMap(lat, longi, R.drawable.marker2, title);
}

private void setUpMap(double lat, double lng, int drawableResource, String title) {
    if(map != null) {
        marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(drawableResource)));
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 15));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13), 2500, null);
    }
}
```